# How to view current php myadmin credential in linux

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

I don't set any password for the phpmyadmin installation. but now it ask user name and password.

i entered the username is root and just press enter button.

but it shows "#1045 Cannot log in to the MySQL server" error message.

please any one help to me...

Comment: What user name are you using? The default is "root". Are you able to connect from the command line client (probably with `mysql -u root`)?

Answer (score 1):

1) In your phpmyadmin file config.inc.php

Find the line:

`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']='root'`

2) Change "root" to the password of your MySql root user.

- In case you didn't set a password for Mysql, login to your mysql
  console and type the following command:

  ```
   UPDATE mysql.userSET Password=PASSWORD("YourNewPassword") WHERE User="root";
  ```

  and the change the line: 
  `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']='root'`

  as follows
  `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']='YourNewPassword`

Note: **YourNewPassword is the password you set in mysql console**

Hope it helps.

Regards
Kheshav

Comment: already have changed "config.inc.php" this file. but same error is occurring. please any one help me.

Comment: Thanks for your response.I fixed that issue